# Hosting for a medium sized Python/Django App

Tags: python, django, hosting

I'm planning to build an app with **Python/Django** with a web interface and web services providing data feeds for mobile apps.

The solution should be **scaleable**. 
Since there is obviously no guarantee that a lot of people will use the service I can't really tell how big the project gonna become. But it should be at least designed to scale quite a bit.

The data being served will mostly be text and pictures, so no need for the real heavy stuff for things like video or audio streaming, real time search and so on.

My question is, what host (best based in **Europe**) would you recommend?
I'm not so confident using Appengine due to evental lock-in effects and its data base restrictions. But if anyone can share good experiences with it, let me hear them.

Comment: Does anyone have experiences with http://djangohosting.ch/ ?

Comment: Almost 2 years later... We tried some cloud hosters and sticked with www.profitbricks.de . We're pretty happy with the price and service. One main requirement was the location of the servers (Germany). US hosting providers are compatible with German data protection laws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webfaction is the most recommended hosting in Python/Django world :)

http://www.webfaction.com/

Comment: So from what i read webfaction seems to be really good... But what consequences could it have for me hosting an application overseas? I and my clients are based in europe.

Comment: They have a pretty good replication. Also the latency also very low. Even we guys in india use it without much hassles. So you can go for it :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are comfortable with setting up the server yourself, you can use http://linode.com, they are a US company with servers in the UK.

Here you can scale up the resources of the server very easily.

Comment: i don't mind setting up the server myself, but it would be better to focus solely on development. server maintenance can become a time consuming task.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard good things about [DjangoEurope](http://djangoeurope.com/).

They have servers located in Germany, France and Switzerland.

Comment: Thanks for that. What is the number of processes in the hosting plans exactly about? When is a new process started? How can I determine how many processes I need?

Answer (score 1):

Now 4 years later I would recommend [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/).

- Pretty easy to setup.
- Good balance of useful features and ease of use.
- Stable.
- Good pricing.

I would recommend digital ocean especially for early stages. If you are lucky and need to scale your app you can still migrate to a hosting company offering more advanced stuff like AWS.

Don't make the same mistake we did. We **over-engineered** our server architecture way too early!

If you need to comply with european data privacy laws I would recommend [Hetzner](https://www.hetzner.de/).